# How do you enable speaker output while headphones are on for SELECT programs?

Tags: windows-8, audio, headphones, alarm-clock

For example, I like to game with headphones on, I listen to music with headphones on and more. I keep the headphones on for many reasons such as not disturbing the neighbors. I don't like to unplug them every time I'm done, that's too confusing and more importantly, I FORGET ALL THE TIME. So, if anyone could kindly help me find a way to play my "Free Alarm Clock" (please Google to find it because I'm afraid to post links) through the speakers despite having headphones plugged in, I would greatly appreciate it. I use it not only to wake up but also to remind me of other daily things.

Just to be clear: I'm not looking for something to play sound through headphones and speakers simultaneously. That would defeat the purpose.

A command would also work.

Comment: Hrm, if you got a second sound card or something, then find some kind of virtual mixer software that sends audio from software to different cards.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is generally a hardware switch. I don't believe it can be defeated in the manner you wish.