# How can I play some audio through speakers, and some through headset?

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers, sound-card, headphones

Is there a setting so that I can choose to have one program play sound through the speakers, and one program play sound through a headset?

This question is related to

[How do you enable speaker output while headphones are on for SELECT programs?](https://superuser.com/questions/712989/how-do-you-enable-speaker-output-while-headphones-are-on-for-select-programs)

My goal is to be able to listen to an audio book through my headset before I fall asleep, and to wake up to my computer alarm clock (playing sound through speakers) in the morning.

A way to make the computer automatically switch where to output sound at a given time will also solve the problem.

For instance: Play through headset until 5am, then play through speakers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only do this if you have an adapter connected through any port except the Audio jack port.

For instance, I use SOUND BLASTER X-FI GO! PRO sound card, a small sound card that is plugged via USB. I use it when I need much higher quality sounds to play through my headset. While Windows sounds, are still turned on laptop speakers, and both are separate. The sounds that I hear on my headset cannot be heard on my laptop speakers, same goes for laptop speakers. All I needed is just configuring the sounds output via Windows Playback devices, and also via changing the program (such as Adobe Audition) settings that I need to make SOUND BLASTER X-FI GO! PRO its default Playback.

So, you need an adapter that has a built-in sound system with output audio jack ports and any input port for connecting it to the computer such as USB or HDMI. It can be a sound card, TV, a Home theater ..etc. Then, you can configure the Playback devices settings from the Windows Playback devices, and also from the program settings that you will use to play audio books.